# In Race Program, can not seem to declare winner when it collides with finish line- java

Tags: java

I am creating a code that contains moving graphics in a JPanel. It is a race code with 3 racers. Every time the timer goes through, there is a 75% chance they move, and a 25% chance they hold.

My problem is with getting the program to print out the winner in the system console. For some reason, it always says "Orange" is the winner, just because it is the last color I added.

The intersections are just when the runners touch the finish line. There are a few custom commands but those are just to draw the background and set up the JPanel. Those work fine. The problem is that for some reason, the X value of the 4 runners seems to be every single value at once.

```
public class Rivals extends JFrame{

    Rivals(){
        Make.frame(this,new RivalsPane(), 512,512,JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE, false);
    }

public static class RivalsPane extends JPanel implements ActionListener{
    Timer t = new Timer(1,this);
    static int x=70,x2=70,x3=70,x4=70,speed=5;
    static boolean done=false;
    static String win = " wins", winner; 

    RivalsPane(){
        Make.panel(this,512,512,null);  
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Make.FootRaceTrack(g);

        Run(g);

        t.start();
    }

    public void Run(Graphics g) {
        Paint.setPen(Color.blue);
        Paint.shadeOval(g,x,90,30,30);
        Paint.setPen(Color.pink);
        Paint.shadeOval(g,x2,190,30,30);
        Paint.setPen(Color.green);
        Paint.shadeOval(g, x3, 290, 30, 30);
        //This is the last one I set, and it always wins
        Paint.setPen(Color.ORANGE); 
        Paint.shadeOval(g, x4, 390, 30, 30);

        Rectangle r1 = new Rectangle(x-30,60, 60, 60);
        Rectangle r2 = new Rectangle(x-30,160, 60, 60);
        Rectangle r3 = new Rectangle(x-30,260, 60, 60);
        Rectangle r4 = new Rectangle(x-30,360, 60, 60);
        Rectangle r5 = new Rectangle(400,0,512,512);

        if(r1.intersects(r5)) { 
            speed = 0; 
            winner ="Blue"; 
            done = true; 
        } else if(r2.intersects(r5)) { 
            speed=0;
            winner = "Pink"; 
            done = true;
        } else if(r3.intersects(r5)) {
            speed=0;
            winner = "Green";
            done = true;
        } else if(r4.intersects(r5)) {
            speed=0;
            winner = "Orange";
            done = true;
        }
if(done==true) System.out.println(winner + "wins");
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        double rand1 = Math.random();
        double rand2 = Math.random();
        double rand3 = Math.random();
        double rand4 = Math.random();
        if(rand1<.75)x+=speed;
        if(rand2<.75)x2+=speed;
        if(rand3<.75)x3+=speed;
        if(rand4<.75)x4+=speed;
        repaint();
    }   
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    Do.showFrame(new Rivals());
}   
}
```

Comment: In the last if statement in run(), you've left out the brackets. This leaves the statement 'winner = orange;' outside the if statements.

Comment: You should use a code editor which will do the indentation for you so these sort of errors will be obvious. Atom is free, if you're using Windows, notepad++ is free.

Comment: I gave the question a +1 because you included the code and a good explanation without being asked to.

Comment: After putting the brackets in, now it just displays blue as the winner.

Comment: If `r1.intersects(r5)` always returns true, then `winner` would always be `"Blue"`. That'd be my starting point

Comment: @Rogue that is my problem. I don’t know why, but it seems that the bounding rectangle of the runners is always intersecting the finish line.

Comment: Why is your `x` position for all rectangles depends on `x` variable and not `x2, x3, x4`?

Comment: @Oh that might be it- let me check and get back to you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cause of your `x` position for all rectangles depends on `x` variable and not `x2, x3, x4`.  From comment.

Answer (score 0):

All my bounding rectangles were using x with applies to blue only. Change the x's to x2,x3, and x4 and it works. Credit to @Alex